# Checking the contents of the tuple in Python

Tags: python, search, indexing, tuples, element

How would I be able to write a function that checks a tuple if it contains at least 2 `H` elements in the list. So for the example below there are 2 tuples in `A` that contain 2 `H` elements `{('H', 'H', 'H', 'T') and ('T', 'H', 'H', 'T')}`?

```
A = [('H', 'H', 'H', 'T'), ('T', 'T', 'T', 'T'), ('T', 'H', 'H', 'T'), ('T', 'T', 'T', 'H'),]
```

Comment: `item.count('H') >= 2`

Comment: I meant to say the total items not just where it sums up all the tuple that have atleast 2 `H`s. Which in the example above is 2

Comment: Once you identify the tuples that match the condition, you can do anything you want with them -- put them in another list, count them, etc.

Comment: use `for`-loop to work with items on list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tuple.count()` method to count the number of `H` elements. Then you can use `sum()` to total the number of times this is at least 2.

```
A = [('H', 'H', 'H', 'T'), ('T', 'T', 'T', 'T'), ('T', 'H', 'H', 'T'), ('T', 'T', 'T', 'H'),]
num_2H = sum(item.count('H') >= 2 for item in A)
print(num_2H) # prints 2
```